# Save the open state of tabs in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am creating a project. I've to work with many routes and tabs inside it. My problem is that I want my browser to remember that which tab was opened before refreshing the page.Suppose I have 3 tabs on 1 page and I opened the 2nd or 3rd tab, than I refresh the page it kick me back to 1st tab. How to prevent this.Is their any solution ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use child routes. Each tab would content a `<router-view>` element, which corresponds to a page within a page.

See `vue-router` docs on [Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/my-page',
    component: MainPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        component: Tab1Content,
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        component: Tab2Content,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

```html
<!-- On /my-page/tab-2, Tab2Content will be rendered in the <router-view> -->
<template>
  <v-tab>
    <router-view /> <!-- Sub route -->
  </v-tab>
</template>
```

Comment: Is their not any other to do this like any plugin etc? because my project is very big and i already have so many routes,so i dont want to mess with routes

Comment: Well you can use `localStorage` to store the last opened tab on the browser. Then on mounted, you get that persisted value to open the right tab.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this. Can we fetch it by using url like if we have route ```home/tabs``` than can we change it by clicking on each tab like ```home/tabs/#tab1``` without adding new route. I mean can we achive this functionality just by js?

Comment: Add a hash (`#`) to the url it totally doable, it doesn't require to specify a route :) Keep in mind it's only accessible on client side though: `this.$router.push({ hash: 'tab1' })`

Comment: can you refer me a proper example where i can see and implement this hash?